# Getting god, resque and log4r to work well together

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, resque, god

i'm using god to manage my resque workers. i'm also using log4r throughout my rails app, and resque jobs, until i setup god.

How do i make god play nice with log4r on my resque workers? If I don't set the log property on my watch, I don't get any logging. But if i set it explicitly then I won't get the benefit of log4r's rolling logs.

help anyone?